# Applying condition around \intertext and \shortintertext leaves excess vertical space

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, conditionals, etoolbox

When I try to make either `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` conditional I get excess vertical spacing prior to the conditional text as per the MWE below. Note the excess vertical spacing prior to *"Albert insisted that"* and *"but we know"*.

The `minipage` on the right represents the correct spacing as it does not have the `\ConditionalText{}` macro applied.

[image]

However, when the conditional is disabled, via the `\toggletrue{}`, the text is suppressed and the spacing is fine:

[image]

### Notes:

- It seems that with

  ```
  \NewDocumentCommand{\ConditionalText}{O{red} +m}{#2}%
  ```

  the spacing problem is still there. However, the problem is resolved if I use the `\iftoggle` directly within the `align` environment as:

  ```
  \newcommand{\TextWithConditional}{%
      \hfill\textbf{Intertext with Conditionals}\hfill%
      Newton said:
      \begin{align*}
          F &= ma \\
          \iftoggle{SupressConditionalText}{}{\intertext{Albert insisted that}}
          E &=mc^2 \\
          \iftoggle{SupressConditionalText}{}{\shortintertext{but we know}}
          E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
      \end{align*}
      Text after a conditional display math formula.%
  }%
  ```

### Failed Solution:

- Well, I had what I thought was a brilliant fix, but it seems that all I can do is to quote Edison and say "I have discovered a method that does *not* work".
  Not sure why it does not work though.

  ```
  \NewDocumentCommand{\ConditionalText}{O{red} +m}{%
      \ignorespaces%
      \iftoggle{SupressConditionalText}{}{%
          \ifmmode%
              \let\OldIntertext\intertext%
              \let\OldShortIntertext\shortintertext%
              \def\intertext{\vspace*{\baselineskip}\OldIntertext}%
              \def\shortintertext{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\OldShortIntertext}%            
              #2% Don't underline if in math mode
          \else%
              %\UnderlineText[#1]{#2}% This case not used in this MWE.
          \fi%
      }%
      \ignorespacesafterend%
  }%
  ```

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% Not essential for this problem.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{parskip}% Eliminate need for \noindent
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newtoggle{SupressConditionalText}%

\togglefalse{SupressConditionalText}% This has too much space BEFORE the conditional \intertext.


\NewDocumentCommand{\UnderlineText}{O{red} +m}{%
    \setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}%
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\ConditionalText}{O{red} +m}{%
    \ignorespaces%
    \iftoggle{SupressConditionalText}{}{%
        \ifmmode%
            #2% Don't underline if in math mode
        \else%
            \UnderlineText[#1]{#2}%
        \fi%
    }%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}%

\newcommand{\TextWithConditional}{%
    \hfill\textbf{Intertext with Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton \ConditionalText{often} said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \intertext{Albert \ConditionalText{awkwardly} insisted that}
        E &=mc^2 \\
        \ConditionalText{\shortintertext{but we know}}
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \\
        \ConditionalText{\intertext{But, equating the two we obtain.}}    
        mc^2 &= \frac{1}{2}mv^2
        \shortintertext{from which \ConditionalText{we obtain}}
        v &= \sqrt{2}c
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%


\newcommand{\TextWithoutConditional}{%
    \hfill\textbf{Intertext without Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \intertext{Albert awkwardly insisted that}
        E &=mc^2 \\
        \shortintertext{but we know}
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%
\newcommand{\TextWithoutConditionalWithoutInterText}{%
    \hfill\textbf{No Intertext, No Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        E &=mc^2 \\
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithConditional
\end{minipage}
\hfill\vrule\hfill% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithoutConditional
\end{minipage}

\bigskip\hrule
\toggletrue{SupressConditionalText}%  Disable conditional text
%
With conditional text supressed, things work fine:

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithConditional
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithoutConditionalWithoutInterText
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an expandability issue.  `\intertext` uses the TeX primitive `\noalign` to insert text which is not aligned with the rest.  This primitive may only appear just after `\\ ` (well, after the underlying `\cr` primitive).  More precisely, TeX expands what follows (and ignores spaces) until finding a non-expandable token.  If that token is `\noalign`, then it prepares to put stuff out of the alignment.  Now, `\intertext` is clever, and does some (expandable) tests to make sure that it is preceeded by `\\ `, adding it if needed.  Since your condition is non-expandable, `\\ ` gets inserted.

Comment: So the solution is: use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` (make sure that all arguments are either long or short) and remove `\ignorespaces` from the beginning of the definition of `\ConditionalText`

Comment: @cgnieder: Can you post an answer? When I use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\ConditionalText}{O{red} m}` _and_ comment out `\ignorespaces` it seems as if the value of the `toggle` is completely ignored, which I don't get at all. This has to be something obvious, but I am not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: @PeterGrill I believe you get the empty branch of the `\ifmmode` conditional...

Comment: @cgnieder: Duh!!! Yeah that makes sense. But that means that I am _not_ in math mode at that point so should be able to use the `\UnderlineText`, but that yields `Misplaced \noalign` (if I un-comment the related code). Can't wait until the day that expansion makes sense to me...

Comment: @PeterGrill as Bruno said: you cannot use anything in `\ConditionalText` that is not expandable before `\intertext`. Since you supply `\intertext` as argument you get `\setulcolor{red}\ul{\intertext{<text>}}` while it should be `\intertext{\setulcolor{red}\ul{<text>}}`. Every assignment (like `\setulcolor{red}`) is not expandable.

Comment: @PeterGrill You are not in math mode when tex scans ahead looking for omit and the `\ifmmode` is expanded at that point, but then if it doesn't find `\noalign` or `\omit` it inserts the `halign` preamble which in this case is from align so that starts math mode and then TeX re-processes the tokens. Normal way to stop that is to make your command robust so that it doesn't expand in the initial scan, but you can't do that as then `\intertext` won't be seen.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So, are you saying that there is not a way to get conditional `\intertext`?  That seems very unlikely, must have misunderstood.

Comment: No I'm just saying you need to step carefully to avoid waking sleeping dragons.

Comment: In particular where do you want `ConditionalText` to be used? If it is only in `align` then it's easy: just don't test for `\ifmmode` If it is always used at the start of some kind of alignment row you can hide teh non expandable tests in `\noalign` if it needs to work both in alignments and normal texts it's a bit harder but not impossible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what I think you want and keeps the tests expandable, it takes the math branch if you are in `align*` or `ifmmode` is true. It would need extending for other environmants.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% Not essential for this problem.
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{parskip}% Eliminate need for \noindent
%\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{SupressConditionalText}%

\togglefalse{SupressConditionalText}% This has too much space BEFORE the conditional \intertext.

% Not used in this paritcular example
\NewDocumentCommand{\UnderlineText}{O{red} +m}{%
    \setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}%
}%

\def\xaligns{align*}
\def\ConditionalText#1{%
    \iftoggle{SupressConditionalText}{}{%
        \ifx\@currenvir\xaligns
          #1%
        \else\ifmmode
           #1% Don't underline if in math mode
        \else%
           \UnderlineText[red]{#1}% This case not used in this MWE.
        \fi
       \fi
    }%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}%

\newcommand{\TextWithConditional}{%
    \hfill\textbf{Intertext with Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \ConditionalText{\intertext{Albert insisted that}}
        E &=mc^2 \\
        \ConditionalText{\shortintertext{but we know}}
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%

\newcommand{\TextWithoutConditional}{%
    \hfill\textbf{Intertext without Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        \intertext{Albert insisted that}
        E &=mc^2 \\
        \shortintertext{but we know}
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%
\newcommand{\TextWithoutConditionalWithoutInterText}{%
    \hfill\textbf{No Intertext, No Conditionals}\hfill%
    Newton said:
    \begin{align*}
        F &= ma \\
        E &=mc^2 \\
        E &=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
    \end{align*}
    Text after a conditional display math formula.%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithConditional
\end{minipage}
\hfill\vrule\hfill% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithoutConditional
\end{minipage}

\bigskip\hrule
\toggletrue{SupressConditionalText}%  Disable conditional text
%
With conditional text supressed, things work fine:

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithConditional
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vrule\hfill% 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \TextWithoutConditionalWithoutInterText
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty good. But, there an extra space if used as `\intertext{Albert \ConditionalText{insisted} that}` for the case where the conditional text is suppressed. I will update the MWE to include this test.

Comment: hmph am I allowed to patch `\intertext` so it resets the current environment?

Comment: Huh? You are asking me? I'd say of course, but is there a reason why that should not be done?