# Redefine \intertext and \shortintertext to measure their width

Tags: math-mode, spacing, align, varwidth

I am trying to measure the *natural width* of an `align*` (with the `fleqn` documentclass option) and have been told in the comments at
[Determine natural width of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394945/4301) that `\intertext` uses the entire `\linewidth`. So, solution *sounds* simple, redefine `\intertext` (and `\shortintertext` and measure them separately via `\varwidth`.

The problem is that it seems tricky to redfine those two macros as using a `\let` seems to be ingored.  The MWE is intended to address the last two test cases by measuing the width of the `\intertext` and `\shorintertext` separately from the remainder of the `align*`.

[image]

### References:

- [Determine natural width of align*: varwidth uses \linewidth even though display is correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394945/4301)
- [align* in varwidth seems to ignore fleqn option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394778/4301)
- This is related question but the answer did not involve redefining `\intertext`: [Applying condition around \intertext and \shortintertext leaves excess vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99539/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}

\makeatletter
%% Fix for varwidth to work with fleqn option
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394778/align-in-varwidth-seems-to-ignore-fleqn-option
\let\@vwid@eqmodetrue\@vwid@eqmodefalse

\newsavebox{\@IntertextSavebox}
\newlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}
\newcommand{\MeasureIntertext}[1]{%
    \savebox{\@IntertextSavebox}{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
            #1%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    %% Keep track of the maximum width of any \shorintertext and
    %% \intertext within this align* environment.
    \ifdim\wd\@IntertextSavebox>\@MaxIntertextWidth
        \setlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}{\wd\@IntertextSavebox}%
    \fi
}%
\newsavebox{\@NonIntertextBox}
\newcommand{\GetNaturalVarwidth}[3]{%
    %% #1 = length to contain the width
    %% #2 = title for this test case
    %% #3 = text to measure
    \setlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}{0pt}%
    \savebox{\@NonIntertextBox}{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
            %% ------------------------------------------------------ Problem Area
            %% This attempt to redefine these two seems to be ignored.
            \let\shortintertext\MeasureIntertext
            \let\intertext\MeasureIntertext
            %% ------------------------------------------------------ 
            #3%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    %% ------------------------------------------
    %% For debugging purposes show the box.
    \medskip\par
    \noindent%
    {\bfseries#2}%
    \par\noindent
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \fbox{%
        \usebox{\@NonIntertextBox}%
    }%
    \ifdim\wd\@IntertextSavebox>\wd\@NonIntertextBox
        \setlength{#1}{\wd\@IntertextSavebox}%
    \else
        \setlength{#1}{\wd\@NonIntertextBox}%
    \fi
    {\par\tiny Natural Width is \printlength{#1}.}%
}%
\makeatother

\newlength{\NaturalWidth}
\begin{document}
\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Small text}{Small text}% Works

%% These two don't work, but right now am just focusing on align*
%\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single Display Equation}{%
%\[
%    F = ma.
%\]
%}
%
%\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single display equation with text}{%
%Single display equation
%\[
%    F = ma.
%\]
%and some more text.%
%}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single align*}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma.
\end{align*}%
}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with text}{%
Famous Equations:
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
or at least they should be famous.
}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with shortintertext}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    \shortintertext{and}
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
}
This one above should be 23.42914mm.

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with intertext}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    \intertext{with some longer intertext}
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
}
This one above should be greater than 23.42914mm 
(which is width of just the nonintertext portion).

\end{document}
```

---

### Listfiles

Am getting an error

```
Undefined control sequence.
\shortintertext ...th }\normalbaselines \if_dim:w
```

while running the provided answer so thought I should include the output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
   fleqn.clo    2016/12/29 v1.2a Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
mathtools.sty    2018/01/08 v1.21 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
printlen.sty    2009/09/03 v1.1a print lengths with units
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Answer (score 1):

Package `amsmath` defines `\intertext` to cause an error message, if it is used outside of some environments, where it is supported. It uses `\intertext@` to define `\intertext` in these environments. Therefore, `\intertext@` needs to be redefined.

`\shortintertext` is provided by package `mathtools` and can be redefined directly.

The following code snippet replaces `\vbox{...}` by `\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}...\end{varwidth}` in `\intertext` and `\shortintertext`:

```
\def\intertext@measuring{% see \intertext@ in amsmath
  \def\intertext##1{%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{%
      \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
      %\vbox{
      \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
        \normalbaselines
        \ifdim\linewidth=\columnwidth
        \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \fi
        \noindent##1\par
      %}%
      \end{varwidth}%
      \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
    }%
  }%
}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\shortintertext@measuring#1{% see \MT_shortintertext:n in mathtools
  \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
  \noalign{%
    \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep
    %\vbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
      \normalbaselines
      \if_dim:w
        \if_dim:w \@totalleftmargin=\z@
          \linewidth
        \else:
          -\maxdimen
        \fi:
        =\columnwidth
      \else:
        \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
      \fi:
      \noindent#1\par
    %}%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip%
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep
  }%
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
```

Then, the redefinitions commands:

```
\let\shortintertext\shortintertext@measuring
\let\intertext@\intertext@measuring
```

The measurement of the example is now improved:

> [image: Result]

Full example (just the example from the question with the added code from this answer):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}

\makeatletter

\def\intertext@measuring{% see \intertext@ in amsmath
  \def\intertext##1{%
    \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
    \noalign{%
      \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\belowdisplayskip
      %\vbox{
      \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
        \normalbaselines
        \ifdim\linewidth=\columnwidth
        \else \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
        \fi
        \noindent##1\par
      %}%
      \end{varwidth}%
      \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayskip%
    }%
  }%
}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\shortintertext@measuring#1{% see \MT_shortintertext:n in mathtools
  \ifvmode\else\\\@empty\fi
  \noalign{%
    \penalty\postdisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep
    %\vbox{%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
      \normalbaselines
      \if_dim:w
        \if_dim:w \@totalleftmargin=\z@
          \linewidth
        \else:
          -\maxdimen
        \fi:
        =\columnwidth
      \else:
        \parshape\@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
      \fi:
      \noindent#1\par
    %}%
    \end{varwidth}%
    \penalty\predisplaypenalty\vskip\abovedisplayshortskip%
    \vskip-\lineskiplimit
    \vskip\normallineskiplimit
    \vskip\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep
  }%
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

%% Fix for varwidth to work with fleqn option
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394778/align-in-varwidth-seems-to-ignore-fleqn-option
\let\@vwid@eqmodetrue\@vwid@eqmodefalse

\newsavebox{\@IntertextSavebox}
\newlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}
\newcommand{\MeasureIntertext}[1]{%
    \savebox{\@IntertextSavebox}{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
            #1%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    %% Keep track of the maximum width of any \shorintertext and
    %% \intertext within this align* environment.
    \ifdim\wd\@IntertextSavebox>\@MaxIntertextWidth
        \setlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}{\wd\@IntertextSavebox}%
    \fi
}%
\newsavebox{\@NonIntertextBox}
\newcommand{\GetNaturalVarwidth}[3]{%
    %% #1 = length to contain the width
    %% #2 = title for this test case
    %% #3 = text to measure
    \setlength{\@MaxIntertextWidth}{0pt}%
    \savebox{\@NonIntertextBox}{%
        \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
            %% ------------------------------------------------------ Problem Area
            %% This attempt to redefine these two seems to be ignored.
            %\let\shortintertext\MeasureIntertext
            \let\shortintertext\shortintertext@measuring
            %\let\intertext\MeasureIntertext
            \let\intertext@\intertext@measuring
            %% ------------------------------------------------------ 
            #3%
        \end{varwidth}%
    }%
    %% ------------------------------------------
    %% For debugging purposes show the box.
    \medskip\par
    \noindent%
    {\bfseries#2}%
    \par\noindent
    \fboxsep=0pt
    \fbox{%
        \usebox{\@NonIntertextBox}%
    }%
    \ifdim\wd\@IntertextSavebox>\wd\@NonIntertextBox
        \setlength{#1}{\wd\@IntertextSavebox}%
    \else
        \setlength{#1}{\wd\@NonIntertextBox}%
    \fi
    {\par\tiny Natural Width is \printlength{#1}.}%
}%
\makeatother

\newlength{\NaturalWidth}
\begin{document}
\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Small text}{Small text}% Works

%% These two don't work, but right now am just focusing on align*
%\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single Display Equation}{%
%\[
%    F = ma.
%\]
%}
%
%\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single display equation with text}{%
%Single display equation
%\[
%    F = ma.
%\]
%and some more text.%
%}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Single align*}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma.
\end{align*}%
}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with text}{%
Famous Equations:
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
or at least they should be famous.
}

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with shortintertext}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    \shortintertext{and}
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
}
This one above should be 23.42914mm.

\GetNaturalVarwidth{\NaturalWidth}{Align* with intertext}{%
\begin{align*}
    F &= ma. \\
    \intertext{with some longer intertext}
    E &= mc^2,
\end{align*}%
}
This one above should be greater than 23.42914mm 
(which is width of just the nonintertext portion).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you pleasepost a  fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) as I am having difficluty getting this to run. I get `Undefined control sequence \shortintertext ...th }\normalbaselines \if_dim:w`.  With _just_ `\let\intertext@\intertext@measuring` I get `Package amsmath Error: Invalid use of \shortintertext.` and with _just_ `\let\shortintertext\shortintertext@measuring` I get identical results as my MWE.

Comment: Also, for handling the single equation environment (commented test cases above) shodul I post a separate question or is there an easy fix to those with this code?

Comment: @PeterGrill Full example added (quite long, therefore I had omitted it).

Comment: Hmmm, I have the same problem as before `Undefined control sequence: shortintertext ...th }\normalbaselines \if_dim:w`.  I just updated all packages and saw that `etoolbox v2.5e` was new, but it sill fails. Have added output of `\listfiles` to the question.

Comment: Finally got to the bottom of the problem here. It appears that somehow an older (2016 or earlier) `mathtools` package was used when you ran this MWE. The `\if_dim` no longer exists. The macros in `mathtools` in TeXLive2017 are prefixed with `\MH_`.